# Allow selection of multiple values for Drupal Facets (Facet API + Search API)

Tags: jquery, drupal-7, filtering, faceted-search

I am using Facet API + Search API to develop Filtering for the data within my site. I am also using Ajax Facet Filters to process the selection as soon as it's clicked.

It all came out great but there's one slight problem. I can only select one option per category. As soon as I select an option, all the inactive options hide and only the active (clicked one) shows.

I want the option to select multiple option but with my settings of Facet API & Search API, there seems to be no option.

Here's the picture to explain.
[image]

I'll be very thankful for any assistance.

Best.

- picture taken from :- https://drupal.org/node/1669600#comment-6190924

Answer (score 0):

Thats because you are using `backDatabase Search`.

Use Apache Solr backend.

Comment: just for this feature do I need to change my entire search engine? There must be a  better way.